# Can you detect Kafka Producer failing with ack=1?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The `Kafka 0.9.0.1` Producer `ack` documentation states:-

```
acks=1 This will mean the leader will write the record to its local log but
will respond without awaiting full acknowledgement from all followers.
In this case should the leader fail immediately after acknowledging the record
but before the followers have replicated it then the record will be lost.
```

How can I detect the record was lost in this failure scenario?
So that I can stop sending subsequent messages?

Comment: Why not just increase to `ack=all` ?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, because ack=all is too slow

Comment: I guess, that is exactly the tradeoff you have to deal with; "strong consistency" vs performance. As you state "stop sending subsequent messages" -- if you can write the next message only if the previous one got safely written, `ack=all` should be the quickest way to verify a successful write... You could also read messages back to see it is is there, but this seems to be way slower than `ack=all`.

Comment: I dont have to trade off if I can detect the ack=1 failure. ack=all is way to slow, the Kafka developers need to work on improving its performance, using ack=all restricts my throughput to 200 messages per second where ack=1 gives over 700 messages per second